# DSolve expression doesn't evaluate

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

Can *Mathematica* solve $\; d^2/dx^2{}+ (1/x) d/dx\;$ form of equations?
For example, I am trying to solve the system of equations given below:

```
eqn1 = D[w[x], {x, 2}] + (1/x) (D[w[x], x]) - w[x];
eqn2 = D[v[x], {x, 2}] + (1/x) (D[v[x], x]) - (v[x] - u[x]);
eqn3 = D[u[x], {x, 2}] + (1/x) (D[u[x], x]) + v[x] - u[x] - w[x];
eqnSet = {eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, eqn3 == 0, w[1] == 0, v[1] == 0, 
      u[1] == 0, w'[0] == 0, v'[0] == 0, u'[0] == 0};
DSolve[eqnSet, {w[x], v[x], u[x]}, x]
```

I am getting `DSolve` returning the input statement unevaluated.

Comment: Is this 1/x term OK if you specify conditions for x=0?

Comment: This `DSolve[{x D[w[x], {x, 2}] + (D[w[x], x]) - x w[x] == 0, w[1] == 0, 
  w'[0] == 0}, w[x], x]` works but due to the initial conditions it's a trivial solution.

Comment: I missed to see that. Thanks to both of you for pointing out my negligence. Still do we need NDSolve[] or can DSolve[] do the job?

Comment: Just try and see.

Comment: @OleksandrR  I disagree that the question arises due to a simple mistake.  In fact, it arises, because `DSolve` is unable to solve a system of equations that you or I could solve by hand without much difficulty.

Comment: @bbgodfrey do you intend to answer the question? Otherwise I'd not be swayed to vote to reopen. The poster has not been seen for two years.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  I believe that I have answered the question.  Bottom line - "DSolve can solve this problem, but only with considerable assistance.".  As you suggest, the OP is unlikely to see it.  However, others may benefit by seeing that `DSolve` sometimes fails to solve a set of ODEs even though they can be solved.  In that case, helping `DSolve` by breaking up the problem often works.  I also would add that, if this question had been answered just a few days ago, it would not have been considered for closure.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Didn't see that in the review queue :-(

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the 1/x term in the ODEs.  In fact, `eqn1` is the standard equation for the Modified Bessel Function of order `0`.  However, because the three ODEs and their boundary conditions as specified in the question all are homogeneous, the solution must be identically zero.  Because this result is not particularly interesting, consider the solution without boundary conditions.

```
DSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, eqn3 == 0}, {w[x], v[x], u[x]}, x]
```

`DSolve` also claims to be unable to solve these equations, even though they are solvable.  So, we must give it some help.

```
DSolve[eqn1 == 0, w[x], x][[1, 1]]
(* w[x] -> BesselJ[0, I x] C[1] + BesselY[0, -I x] C[2] *)
```

It is very strange that `DSolve` does not express `w` in terms of Modified Bessel Functions.  However, with additional help, the answer can be simplified.

```
cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 100 Count[e, _BesselY, {0, Infinity}]
s1 = FullSimplify[%%, x > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf] /. 
    C[1] -> C[1] + I C[2] /. C[2] -> -C[2] π/2    
(* w[x] -> BesselI[0, x] C[1] + BesselK[0, x] C[2] *)
```

Next, we observe that `eqn2 + eqn3` can be simplified greatly by substituting `u[x] + v[x] -> z[x]`.

```
Simplify[(eqn2 + eqn3) /. {v'[x] -> -u'[x] + z'[x], v''[x] -> -u''[x] + z''[x]} /. s1];
s2 = FullSimplify[DSolve[% == 0, z[x], x][[1, 1]], x > 0]
(* z[x] -> (-1 + BesselI[0, x]) C[1] + BesselK[0, x] C[2] + C[4] + C[3] Log[x] *)
```

To obtain an expression for `v[x]`, we eliminate `u[x]` in terms of `z[x]` from `eqn2` and solve.

```
eqn2 /. {u[x] -> -v[x] + z[x]} /. s2
s3 = FullSimplify[DSolve[% == 0, v[x], x][[1, 1]], x > 0] /. 
    C[5] -> C[5] + I C[6] /. C[6] -> -C[6] π/2
(* v[x] -> 1/2 (-C[1] + 2 BesselI[0, x] C[1] + 2 BesselK[0, x] C[2] + C[4] + 
   2 BesselI[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[5] + 2 BesselK[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[6] + C[3] Log[x]) *)
```

Finally, we obtain `u[x]` from `z[x]`.

```
Simplify[((s2 /. z[x] -> u[x] + v[x]) /. Rule -> List) - (s3 /. Rule -> List)] 
    /. List -> Rule
(* u[x] -> 1/2 (-C[1] + C[4] - 2 BesselI[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[5] - 
   2 BesselK[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[6] + C[3] Log[x]) *)
```

Back-substitution shows that these three expression indeed satisfy the oriinal equations.  Thus, `DSolve` can solve this problem, but only with considerable assistance.

**Alternative, more compact solution**

Because the differential operators are the same in all three equations, the equations can be diagonalized, solved with `DSolve`, and transformed back.

```
var = {w[x], v[x], u[x]};
{b, m} = CoefficientArrays[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}, var] // Normal;
{val, vec} = Eigensystem[m]
(* {{-2, -1, 0}, {{0, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}} *)

DSolve[Thread[(b + val var) == 0], var, x] // Flatten;
FullSimplify[%, x > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf] /. 
  {C[1] -> C[1] + I C[2], C[3] -> C[3] + I C[4]} /. {C[2] -> -C[2] π/2, C[4] -> -C[4] π/2};
Transpose[vec].(% /. Rule[_, z_] -> z);
Thread[Rule[var, %]]
(* {w[x] -> BesselI[0, x] C[3] + BesselK[0, x] C[4], 
    v[x] -> -BesselI[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[1] - BesselK[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[2] + 
                BesselI[0, x] C[3] + BesselK[0, x] C[4] + C[6] + C[5] Log[x], 
    u[x] -> BesselI[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[1] + BesselK[0, Sqrt[2] x] C[2] + C[6] + C[5] Log[x]}*)
```

`DSolve` should, in my opinion, be able to perform the diagonalization and provide solutions in terms of Modified Bessel Functions without assistance.